# React Child Component Not Rendering (Table and Rows)

Tags: reactjs, components, react-props

I am trying to use a compound component made up of one Table and multiple Rows to load data dynamically from an API endpoint.

The Ranking component represents the table and lays the format of the table. Its state contains an JSON array of users that gets load after componentDidMount is called. When the state changes the table is re-rendered: The renderRows method iterates over the JSON objects of the state array and the renderRow method creates new Rows (one for each element in the state array).

Everything seems to work but for some reason the Row components never load...

```
function Row(props) {
    console.log("Rendering row");   --> NEVER PRINTS
    return (
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell> {props.name}</TableCell>
        <TableCell> {props.amount}</TableCell>
        <TableCell> {props.country}</TableCell>
        <TableCell> {props.memo} </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    );
  }

class Ranking extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: []     --> gets populated on ComponentDidMount
    };
  }

  renderRow(user) {
    console.log('calling renderRow on ' + user.username);  -> always prints
    return (
      <Row name={user.username}
          amount={user.amount}
          country={user.country}
          memo={user.memo}
          />
        );
  }

  renderRows(userList) {
    for (var i=0; i<userList.length; i++){
      this.renderRow(userList[i]);
    }
  }

   componentDidMount() {
     fetch("/users").then(response => response.json())
     .then(data => this.setState({users: data}))

   }


  render() {
    console.log(this.state.users)  --> prints expected json array
    return (
      <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table aria-label="simple table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell align="right">User</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Amount</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Country</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Memo</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
              {this.renderRows(this.state.users)}    --> is correctly called
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In renderRows function you are not returning anything.

```js
renderRows(userList) {
    return userList.map(user=>this.renderRow(user))
  }
```

This might work.

Comment: thank you! I thought it was enough to have the return statement in the underlying function.

Comment: You are welcome. Happy to help. Please mark it solved.

Comment: done. For the record this helped me understand 2 things:
    -you need to have a return statement for this to work
    -I also tried just adding a return statement to my code but realized that RETURNS after the first iteration of the for loop...keeping my for loop would have been possible if I populated then returned a new array.

Answer (score 0):

You are using this, which refers to a property of the class. The function you are trying to call is outside your class. Remove this and just call renderRows(this.state.users).